# Is $\|u\|_\infty\leq C\|u\|_{L^2}$ true for $u \in H^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for $n>3$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

The Sobolev Lemma says if $u \in H^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$ $(m\in \mathbb{N})$, $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $k<m-n/2$ then $u\in C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and for $|\alpha|\leq k$

$$\sup\limits_x |\partial^\alpha u(x)|\leq C\|u\|_{L^2}$$

For some constant $C$.
Especially if $m=2$ and $n\leq 3$ then $0<2-n/2$. Hence

$$\|u\|_\infty\leq C\|u\|_{L^2}\quad (*)$$

Using $(*)$ one can show that

For $n\leq 3$ and $V \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)+L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and arbitrary $a>0$ there is a constant $b$ such that

$$\|Vu\|_{L^2}\leq a \|\Delta u \|_{L^2}+b\|u\|_{L^2}$$

for all $u \in H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I want to know if this is also true if $n>3$.

**So my question would be**

> is $(*)$ true for $n>3$ or is the second statement true for $n>3$?

Is it maybe possible to apply $(*)$ to $u(x_1,\ldots,x_{3n})$ when we regard it as $u((x_1,\ldots,x_{n}),(x_{n+1},\ldots,x_{2n}),(x_{2n+1},\ldots,x_{3n}))$?

Comment: It fails in general. The reason is that for higher and higher dimensions more and more singularities become integrable (think about $\Vert x\Vert^{-1}$). I have nothing to do a computation right now, but for $n\geq 5$ I'd try to look at something like $$f(x)=\begin{cases} -\ln(\Vert x\Vert^2),& \Vert x\Vert \leq 1, \\ 0,& \Vert x\Vert >1.\end{cases}$$

Comment: An additionnal comment: the strategy you propose at the end, fixing some variable and using the embedding for the remaining of the variables,fails. The idea being that, when you fix one variable you have a loss of $\frac{1}{2}$ derivatives. Like for $s>\frac{1}{2}$, one can prove that $$\mathrm{H}^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow \mathrm{C}^0_b(\mathbb{R}, \mathrm{H}^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})).$$

The idea would be morally to iterate the result $n$-times then to require $s>n/2$ to obtain the embedding.

Comment: As daw correctly points out in his answer $(*)$ is not correct in any dimension. This can be seen by scaling. Namely fix some $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\Vert \varphi\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}=1$ and define for $\varepsilon >0$ the rescaled version $\varphi_\varepsilon(x)=\varepsilon^{n/2}\varphi(\varepsilon x)$. We get $\Vert \varphi_\varepsilon\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}=1$ and $\Vert \varphi_\varepsilon\Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\varepsilon^{n/2}$. Hence, $(*)$ would imply $\varepsilon^{n/2}\leq C$ for some fixed $C\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and all $\varepsilon>0$. A contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If there is $c>0$ such that $\|u\|_{L^\infty} \le c \|u\|_{L^2}$ for all $u\in H^m(\mathbb R^n)$, then it is true for all $u \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$,
hence by density it is true for all $u\in L^2$. This is absurd, so the claim cannot be true.

Then also your initial claim is wrong.

Comment: I don't think that works as bump functions are not dense in $L^2$ wrt the sup-norm. Otherwise your argument would also show that the OPs result in low dimensions is false. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Smooth functions with compact support are dense in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$. If the inequality would be true then it would be true for all $L^2$ functions. The result is false in low dimensions as well (i.e., the first large formula in the question)

Comment: Bump functions are dense in $L^p$ for the $L^p$ norm for $p<\infty$. But your inequality involves the $L^\infty$ norm in which the bump functions are not dense (because the uniform limit of continuous functions would be continuous). So I don't understand how you are using density to get the inequality for all $L^2$ functions.

Comment: If $(u_k)$ is a sequence of smooth functions that is Cauchy in $L^2$, then it is Cauchy in $L^\infty$ by (*). Hence its $L^2$-limit is in $L^\infty$ and satisfies (*) as well. We only need the density with respect to the space/norm on the right-hand side of the inequality. This is a standard argument to prove Sobolev embedding theorems.

Comment: Indeed, sorry, that was a stupid remark on my part. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the issue here is that the OP should replace the $L^2$ norm by the $H^m$ norm?

Comment: Yes, something like that.